# You can select an answer prompt shown before you really can

Tags: bug, status-declined

Let the pictures do the talking
[image]
[image]
Not necessarily a bug, but could be fixed nevertheless.

Comment: Also been asked/reported on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66654/i-was-recommended-to-accept-an-answer-before-it-was-possible

Comment: ... and [status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66654/i-was-recommended-to-accept-an-answer-before-it-was-possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- this reminder only happens for users with low-ish reputation
- we'd rather let someone attempt to do something, and explain why they can't, then just make it invisible or disabled.